# Why does Generator.prototype.return take a value?

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator

I'm trying to figure out why `Generator.prototype.return` takes a value.

I get that it stops the generator from processing and renders each `next` call with:

```
{
    done: true,
    value: undefined,
}
```

But when you pass it a value such as `generator.return(4)`, all it does is give you back an object as if you called `Generator.prototype.next` and your `value` prop was 4.

My only guess is this could be useful when composing generators together or when you're doing some sort of two-way communication; although, since it kills off the generator, two-way communication doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.return()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return) method takes a value because it provides two-way communication in the same way as [`.next()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next) and [`.throw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/throw) do.

A `yield` expression can have 3 different outcomes:

- It can evaluate like a plain expression, to the result value of that
- It can evaluate like a `throw` statement, causing an exception
- It can evaluate like a `return` statement, causing only `finally` statements to be evaluated before ending the function
- (a 4th possible outcome is that the generator never gets resumed)

which are achieved by calling the respective method on the suspended generator with the respective value. This includes the exception value and the return value.

> But when you pass it a value such as `generator.return(4)`, all it does is give you back an object as if you called `Generator.prototype.next` and your value prop was `4`.

Not necessarily. You might think that when a `return` statement is evaluated it always comes back with that return value, and unlike an exception from a `throw` statement it could not be intercepted. It's true that the return value cannot be *accessed* within the generator function, but it can be *suppressed* or changed through a `finally` clause.

```js
[ function* exampleA() {
    try { yield; } finally {}
  },
  function* exampleB() {
    try { yield; } finally { yield 'Y'; }
  },
  function* exampleC() {
    try { yield; } finally { return 'Z'; }
  },
  function* exampleD() {
    try { yield; } finally { throw 'E' }
  }
].forEach(genFn => {
  try {
    const gen = genFn();
    gen.next();
    console.log(gen.return('X'));
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

(Of course, doing such things in a `finally` clause is a bad practice, but it's possible)